# Send JSON from angular.js to node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, node.js

If I send a JSON from frontend angular.js to backend node.js, it give me an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property username of undefined`. I'm using also Express.

**Frontend (Angular.js)**:

```
var username_data = $scope.LoginUsername;
var password_data = $scope.LoginPassword;
var data = {username : username_data, password : password_data};

$http.post('/api/login', data)
.then(function (res) {
    //to do...
});
```

**Backend (node.js) with Restful API:**

```
app.post('/api/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.data.username);
    console.log(req.data.password);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means data does not exists, just try req.body instead

```
app.post('/api/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.username);
    console.log(req.body.password);
});
```

Comment: console.log return `undefined`

Comment: can you post what it is showing when you console.log(req);

Comment: __onFinished: { [Function: listener] queue: [Array] },
 [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: { 'x-powered-by': [Array], vary: [Array] } },  _startAt: [ 12994, 141275677 ],
  _startTime: 2018-01-13T10:30:26.601Z,
  _remoteAddress: '::ffff:127.0.0.1',
  body: { username: 'cccccc', password: 'dddd' },
  _body: true,
  length: undefined,
  read: [Function],
  originalMethod: 'POST',
  route:
   Route {
     path: '/api/login',
     stack: [ [Object] ],
     methods: { post: true } } }
(node:5072) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function witho
ut callback is deprecated.

Comment: sorry if i was not clear in the first time, was posting from mobile